# Conversion to a double-escaped string

Tags: c#, string

In C#, I have a filename that needs to converted to be double-escaped (because I feed this string into a regex).

In other words, if I have:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"c:\windows\foo.txt");
string fileName = file.FullName;
```

`fileName` is: `c:\\\\windows\\\\foo.txt`

But I need to convert this to have sequences of two literal backslashes \\ in the fileName.
fileName needs to be `@"c:\\\\windows\\\\foo.txt"`, or `"c:\\\\\\\\windows\\\\\\\\foo.txt"`.
Is there an easy way to make this conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplest without resorting to regex for this part:

```
string fileName = file.FullName.Replace(@"\", @"\\\\");
```

based on OP, but I think you really want this:

```
string fileName = file.FullName.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

That being said, I can't see how you want to use it... it shouldn't need escaping at all... maybe you should post more code?

Comment: Ah, C# strings have a Replace method! :) That does the trick.

Comment: Oh, and I needed this for feeding that string into a regex. So the backslashes needed to be escaped.

Answer (score 8):

I Think you're looking for [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx)

```
Regex.Escape(@"c:\test.txt") == @"C:\\Test\.txt"
```

notice how it also escapes '.'